# Invalid FORMATETC structure when calling CreateObjectFromFile

Tags: windows, delphi, ms-word, ole

I am using Delphi 7 to try and load a Word document into an OLEContainer. The program is running in a Terminal Services (Windows 2003) environment.

The following code generates the error for some users:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OleContainer1.CreateObjectFromFile('c:\tmp\test.doc', false);
end;
```

It is a simple application with an OLEContainer and a button on a form. The c:\tmp\test.doc is a Word 2003 document.

For some users this code generates the error

> Invalid FORMATETC structure.

For others it does not. All the users run on the same terminal server, thus running the same program accessing the same Word doc. Moreover, all the users were created using a script, so they have the exact same setup, apart from the username and suchlike of course.

I have tried making all the users administrators, but that does not change the behaviour.

Anyone got any ideas what the problem can be?

Comment: It could be a concurrency issue. All of your users have to work with the same document or can you provide a copy for each user?

Comment: The error message contains other information (maybe a error number) or is just the _Invalid FORMATETC structure_?

Comment: Which Delphi version do you use? The OleCreateFromFile call I have in XE3 just pass nil (null) to the _lpFormatEtc_ parameter and OLERENDER_DRAW to _renderopt_. It doesn't look like the point of failure to me. Can you just retry? or generate a StackTrace for the failure to see at which point it occurs?

Comment: It is not a concurrency issue. I tried by logging in, first as user A then user B. Works fine for A, not B. Might be more to the error message, haven't checked. I can't reproduce the error and have no access to the environment where the error occurs. It is written in delphi 7.

Comment: This is for W2K but it may be related "[OLE Interfaces That Use the Formatetc Structure May Not Work with Terminal Services](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=297217)".

Comment: @Sertac I have no Delphi 7 to look, but in XE3 the passed lpFormatEtc pointer is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing I found that the method TOleContainer.LoadFromStream always works. The problem is that this method expects an OLE-stream, not a stream containing a word-document. I reverse engineered the format of the OLE-stream and created one manually by writing the header, the word document and then a footer. The footer, it appears, consists of an even 256-bytes of ASCII-0.

The following is the code for createing the OLE-stream:

```
function OLEStreamFromDoc(const inDocFileName : String) : TMemoryStream;
var
  aFileStream : TMemoryStream;
  aPadding    : Array[1..256] of byte;
  aHeader     : Array[1..12] of byte;
  aSize       : int64;
  i           : integer;
begin
  for i := low(aHeader) to High(aHeader) do
    aHeader[i] := 0;

  for i := low(aPadding) to High(aPadding) do
    aPadding[i] := 0;

  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  aFileStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    aFileStream.LoadFromFile(inDocFileName);
    aFileStream.Seek(0,0);
    aSize := aFileStream.Size + SizeOf(aPadding);

    aHeader[1] := Ord('B');
    aHeader[2] := Ord('D');
    aHeader[3] := Ord('O');
    aHeader[4] := Ord('C');
    aHeader[5] := 1;
    aHeader[9]  := aSize and 255;
    aHeader[10] := (aSize shr 8) and 255;
    aHeader[11] := (aSize shr 16) and 255;
    aHeader[12] := (aSize shr 24) and 255;
    Result.Write(aHeader, SizeOf(aHeader));
    aFileStream.SaveToStream(Result);
    Result.Write(aPadding, sizeof(aPadding));
    Result.Seek(0,0);
  finally
    aFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Word automation supports IPersistFile, this should provide an alternative way to load a file. [See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345216/opening-a-word-doc-document-from-a-stream)